# <select> <option> with default value from a variable

Tags: html, html-select

In brief, in the profile page, I have the following code:

```html
<select  name="sex" >
    <option value="Male"> Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Looks fine :)

However, 
When the user wants to update his choice,,, I have an update profile page where I put the same code as:

```html
<select  name="sex" >
    <option value="Male"> Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

My problem is that I couldn't put the previously selected option as default when the page is loaded... Is there a way to load the page with the previously select option as default ?

Many thanx :)

Comment: where do you store the user's choice in the first place?

Comment: ```<option selected={you check is here}>```

Comment: @AdelLinuix80s What stack (server platform/program language) do you use? In general you need read sex.value and rerender your view in accordance with it.

Comment: Hi thanx for the rapid response

<option selected={your check is here}> won't fit 'cause it will choose a default option! what i need to feed the option from a prevoius input !

I am using java servlet, jsp...mySQL

Comment: Search on google for `jsp option default value` or replace jsp with whatever you're using. I'm 100% sure you'll find tens of answers to your question.

Comment: I did,,, but i don't want the default value....

Comment: Your title SAYS that you want the default value.

Comment: @islam-elshobokshy ....From a variable..

Comment: I got the answer :) by implementing the JSTL -  <c:if> Tag ...

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer :) by implementing the JSTL - <c:if> Tag as follows:

```
<select name="gender">
          <option value="Male" <c:if test="${THE_PATIENT.getGender() == 'Male'}"> selected </c:if>>Male</option>
          <option value="Female" <c:if test="${THE_PATIENT.getGender() == 'Female'}"> selected </c:if>>Female</option>
        
    </select>
```